# Where is .ctags file located in Ubuntu?

Tags: ubuntu, vim, ctags, exuberant-ctags

Where is .ctags file located in Ubuntu? I have exuberant-ctags installed but cannot find it.

I found nothing about this in Google.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`.ctags` is not created by default so you must create it yourself:

```
$ touch ~/.ctags
```